# How to prevent HttpWatch from 404ing javascript single-line comments

Tags: javascript, httpwatch

How do you prevent HttpWatch from interpreting javascript single-line comment as call to a missing resource thus resulting in a 404 error?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should ask the HttpWatch-guys? This has nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

HttpWatch doesn't interpret the javascript - it just records the HTTP traffic generated by the browser. Any 404 error that you see is merely being reported by HttpWatch not generated by it.

If you can provide a .hwl file from HttpWatch or a public URL where this occurs we'll have a look to see why the 404 is generated.

You can contact us directly at support@simtec.ltd.uk.

Answer (score 0):

I think it thinks that the `//…` is intended to be a relative URI just without the scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster could be referring to the invalid URL http://:/ appearing in the HttpWatch log. This is a side effect of a commonly used technique in javascript libraries that attempt to emulate a DOMContentLoaded event in IE:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2007/11/20/error_internet_invalid_url-httpwatch/